# How to use likes to manage plugins in FDT?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, hyperlink, fdt

FDT URL: http://fdt.powerflasher.com/
I want to manage my plugins in FDT. Because FDT is build on eclipse. I try to add links folder.It work in eclipse. But don't work in FDT. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right cLick your AS3 project you want a linked folder for
2. Choose New/Other
3. Select now General/Folderand hit next.
4. CLick Advanced
5. Select "Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)"
6. Browser your folder to link to
7. Type the name of the folder in text field "Folder name:"
8. Hit finish.